# Reuse recipe in google dataprep

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I am trying to use existing recipe from one dataset to another. Unfortunately, i am unable to locate the steps by steps process in the google cloud documentation.

Could someone assist with the steps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you can do that. For example, if you want to keep your recipe/dataset combinations in separate flows, you could make a copy of the flow (there's an option in its menu), go into the flow, choose "Replace" from the menu of the dataset linked to the recipe you want to reuse and give your new dataset as input. If, on the other hand, you'd rather keep everything together in the same flow, you could go into that flow and choose to make a copy of the recipe you want to reuse. Then, from that copy's menu, choose "Change input".